# How to write to a file in Unicode in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, unicode, streamwriter

How should I modify the following Vb.Net code to write `str` to the file in unicode?

Do I need to convert `str` to *Unicode* before writing to the file?

```
Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fname)
    sw.Write(str)
    sw.Close()
End Using
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [overriden constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to specify the encoding

```
Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fname, true, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
    sw.Write(str)
    sw.Close()
End Using
```

Pick either UTF8(8bit) or Unicode(16 bit) character-set encoding as per your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says that `StreamWriter` uses UTF8-Encoding by default.

Comment: +1 Although it's UTF8 without BOM, so you might not realise!. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The below code explicitly instructs to save as UTF-8 without BOM.

```
Dim utf8WithoutBom As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(False)
Dim orfWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, append, utf8WithoutBom)
orfWriter.Write(saveString)
orfWriter.Close()
```

For full documentation, see [www.ezVB.net](http://www.ezvb.net/save-string-or-array-as-text-file/).

Comment: Both your current answers link to the same site. If you are affiliated with this site, you should state it in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about this. Yes, I am affiliated with ezVB.net.